# how to use javamail to add an excel file in mail body

Tags: excel, jakarta-mail

i know how to add an excel file in mail attachment, but now i want to add an  excel file in mail body. it didn't need show content of excel file in mail body.Just Showing an icon is okay, when the reciever clicks the icon , MS office can handle it.

Answer (score 0):

The main body should be html with a link to the excel file, which is stored on your website somewhere.

Comment: like this "<a href="file://server/directory/file.xlsx">Click me!</a>" ?

Comment: Well, yes and no.  You need an http: URL, not a file: URL, if you want the recipient of the message to be able to load it without it being already stored on the recipient's disk.